# Exclude a pattern when it is inside another pattern while pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a String provided to me by a 3rdParty application. I want to tokenise them and make it key value pair.

```
name=\"Student one\" grade=\"fifth grade\" gender=m place=\"some place in this earth\" dob=30/02/1900 enrolled
```

Expected tokenized output is

```
name = \"Student one\"
grade=\"fifth grade\"
gender=m
place=\"some place in this earth\"
dob=30/02/1900
```

I can't simply tokenize based on space as there are some space within \"  \" patter, which i want to omit.

Doing pattern match on 2nd occurrence of \" is also not helpful as i don't have gender=m in between \" \"

How to do a pattern matching based on pattern and avoid doing pattern matching if the input is between \" and \"

Comment: Are there actual backslash characters in the text, or are you showing us the string without surrounding quotes?

Comment: backslash are in the text. This is the exact text i get from my library

Comment: I can do a pattern match on {\\" } -- note it is slash slash double quote space. But i get overlapping tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
(?:\\"[^"\\]*\\"|[^\s\\"])+
```

In Java, it can be used like this (welcome to Java backslash hell):

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
    "(?:           # Start of group, matching...\n" +
    " \\\\\"       # an escaped quote\n" +
    " [^\"\\\\]*   # followed by 0+ characters except backslashes or quotes\n" +
    " \\\\\"       # and another escaped quote\n" +
    "|             # OR\n" +
    " [^\\s\\\\\"] # a character except spaces, backslashes or quotes.\n" +
    ")+            # Repeat as many times as possible (at least once)", 
    Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/qX7gX1).

Comment: Yes. Backslash hell... I am familiar with it :)

Answer (score 1):

A basic Approach Would be using starting and ending of double quote(") to ignore space, if inside a double quote.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String data = "name=\"Student one\" grade=\"fifth grade\" gender=m place=\"some place in this earth\" dob=30/02/1900";


    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    String tmp = "";
    int alternate=1;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); ++i) {

        if(data.charAt(i)=='\"'){
            alternate*=-1;
        }
        if(alternate == 1 && (data.charAt(i)==' '||i==data.length()-1)){
            list.add(tmp);
            tmp="";
        } 
        tmp+=data.charAt(i)+"";
        if(tmp.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){
            tmp="";
        }
    }


    Iterator it = list.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(it.next().toString());
    }


}
```

output

```
name="Student one"
grade="fifth grade"
gender=m
place="some place in this earth"
dob=30/02/190
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one:

```
String s = "name= \\\"Student one\\\" grade=\\\"fifth grade\\\" gender=m place=\\\"some place in this earth\\\" dob=30/02/1900 enrolled";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "\\S+\\s*=\\s*            # Key= with optional spaces around\n"
        +"("
        +"\\\\\"[^\"\\\\]*\\\\\"  # capture in between \"...\" \n"
        +"|                       # OR\n"
        +"\\S+                    # non space characters!\n"
        +")"
        , Pattern.COMMENTS);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
while (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Usually the pattern is like below. For better understanding the comment is added in between the regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+\\s*=\\s*(\\\\\"[^\"\\\\]*\\\\\"|\\S+)");
```